# Set "Retain Original Image Color Depth" crystal report option from c# application in run time

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, crystal-reports

[image]

I am working on a c# desktop application (WinForms) that generates crystal reports with a fair amount of images.
Some users like their images to be high quality, while other are complaining about the report size.

We have tried a lot of image compression methods and even tried to reduce the color depth, but none of them is a really acceptable solution.

The only thing that really works for us is "Retain Original Image Color Depth".

My question(s) is/are:

1. Is there any way that this option can be turned on/off in runtime
   from my c# application?
2. If not, any chance to really replicate the internal algorithm that
   Crystal reports perform when this is ON? We have tried many
   algorithms, but the result is very bad quality or the size
   reduction is not acceptable.